# Editar item dentro da ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Olá. Estou trabalhando num código que carrega itens dentro da **ListView** através de um **adapter**. Dentro de cada item (`item_list.xml`), inseri dois botões sendo um para deletar o item e outro para editar.
O método que deleta o item está funcionando perfeitamente porém não estou conseguindo implementar o método para edita-los.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Abaixo classes pertinentes ao uso das informações mencionadas acima:

**AdapterListView**

```
package com.example.aulasandroid.aulas_android_listviewactions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by lmontanhine on 11/2/2015.
*/
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListView> itens) {
    //Itens que preencheram o listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

/**
 * Retorna a quantidade de itens
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}

/**
 * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public ItemListView getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}

/**
 * Sem implementação
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Pega o item de acordo com a posção.
    ItemListView item = itens.get(position);
    //infla o layout para podermos preencher os dados
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    //atraves do layout pego pelo LayoutInflater, pegamos cada id relacionado
    //ao item e definimos as informações.
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getTexto());
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());
    ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete)).setTag(position);
    ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit)).setTag(item);

    return view;
}
public void removeItem(int positionToRemove){
    itens.remove(positionToRemove);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void updateItens(ArrayList<ItemListView> itens) {
    self.itens = itens;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private AdapterListView adapterListView;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Pega a referencia do ListView
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //Define o Listener quando alguem clicar no item.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    createListView();


}

private void createListView() {
    //Criamos nossa lista que preenchera o ListView
    itens = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();
    ItemListView item1 = new ItemListView("Felpudo", R.drawable.felpudo);
    ItemListView item2 = new ItemListView("Felpudão", R.drawable.felpudo1);
    ItemListView item3 = new ItemListView("Felpudinho", R.drawable.felpudo2);

    itens.add(item1);
    itens.add(item2);
    itens.add(item3);

    //Cria o adapter
    adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

    //Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    //Cor quando a lista é selecionada para ralagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //Pega o item que foi selecionado.
    ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);
    //Demostração
    Toast.makeText(this, "Você Clicou em: " + item.getTexto(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void deletaItem(View v) {
    adapterListView.removeItem((Integer) v.getTag());
}

public void editaItem(View v){
    onItemClick();
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //Posição na lista
    final int selecionado = arg2;

    //Pega o item que foi selecionado.
    ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setText(item.getTexto());
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Alterar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            item.setTexto(value);

            itens.set(selecionado, item);

            adapterListView.updateItens(itens);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}

}
```

**ItemListView**

```
package com.example.aulasandroid.aulas_android_listviewactions;

/**
* Created by lmontanhine on 11/2/2015.
*/
public class ItemListView {

private String texto;
private String nome;
private int iconeRid;

public ItemListView() {
}

public ItemListView(String texto, int iconeRid) {
    this.texto = texto;
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public int getIconeRid() {
    return iconeRid;
}

public void setIconeRid(int iconeRid) {
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}

public String getNome(String nome) {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome (String nome){
    this.nome = nome;
}

}
```

**item_list.xml** (consta informações dos botões que fazem as ações de deletar e editar os itens da lista)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5sp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Editar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="editaItem"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Deletar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="deletaItem"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Em que sentido você pretender realizar essa edição? É uma edição *inline*, abrir outra *activity* ou algo específico? Isso você não especificou, seria bom este detalhe para termos uma direção correta.

Comment: Seria editar o item da lista, na verdade apenas o nome. Imagino que seja necessário criar uma nova activity é um novo layout pra permitir que o usuário digite o nome que será atualizado e após isso, atualizar o item. @PauloRodrigues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou supondo que você criou uma classe **ItemListView** que possui algum atributo que define o texto desta linha na sua lista, certo? Como não parece que você está persistindo estes dados (como *hard coded*), esta seria a solução mais simples, a menos que você precise persistir estes dados em algum local, então o método seria diferente.

Como é apenas alteração de uma string, não optei por uma *activity* para realizar algo bem simples, acredito que uma janela de diálogo resolva esta questão. Então, no clique do botão, você terá algo assim:

```
public void editaItem(View v) {
    //Posição na lista
    final int selecionado = (Integer) v.getTag();

    //Pega o item que foi selecionado.
    final ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(selecionado);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setText(item.getTexto());
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Alterar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            item.setTexto(value);

            itens.set(selecionado, item);

            adapterListView.updateItens(itens);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Note que no seu **adapter** eu precisei criar um método `updateItens` porque você vai precisar alterar os itens nele novamente e informar que os dados foram alterados, assim:

```
public void updateItens(ArrayList<ItemListView> itens) {
    this.itens = itens;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

E a tag deste botão, lá no seu adapter, precisa agora da posição e não do item:

```
((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit)).setTag(position);
```

É algo assim, veja se é isso que você procura e diga.

Comment: O que é `arg2` em `itens.set(arg2, item);`

Comment: É o *index* do item na lista, indicado no método `onItemClick`, onde sugeri adicionar este código.

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta e inseri minha classe **ItemListView** com `getNome` e `setNome` mas para isso, precisei criar a variável **nome** e não vi nenhum lugar do seu código que a utilizasse. Fiquei um pouco perdido em como ficaria minha **MainActivity** com a alteração sugerida por você no primeiro bloco. Você consegue editar considerando a minha classe Main que coloquei aqui na pergunta, inserindo a parte sugerida por você? Obrigado pela ajuda @PauloRodrigues

Comment: @LuizHenriqueUgliano alterei minha resposta com minha sugestão do método `onItemClick`. Na verdade eu havia sugerido esse atributo nome mas depois editei porque eu vi que você já tinha a propriedade **texto**, então como no seu XML, o que você tem de relevante é texto e imagem, é só esse atributo que altera.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues atualizei a **MainActivity** e **AdapterListView** conforme suas sugestões mas ainda estou com os seguintes erros: Na classe **AdapterListView**, não está reconhecendo o "self", da linha `self.itens = itens`. Na classe MainActivity bão estou conseguindo chamar o método onItemClick no método que criei para editar meu botão `public void editaItem`. A variável "item" está solicitando que seja declarada no método onItemClick. É isso mesmo?

Comment: @LuizHenriqueUgliano ops, desculpe, na verdade é **this**. Embolei as linguagens :D

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Na classe MainActivity não estou conseguindo chamar o método onItemClick no método que criei para editar o item através do meu botão `public void editaItem`. A variável "item" está solicitando que seja declarada no método onItemClick. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21103/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-luiz-henrique-ugliano).